# Kolmogorov-Smirnov test - two samples of data - dependence on the width of the bin of the histograms.

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I have just discovered the existence of  Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.I have two samples of data from which I get histograms. Looking at the theory of Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, I had the doubt that its result is influenced by the shape of the histogram. Obviously the shape of the histogram is influenced by the width of the bin, which is a degree of freedom of the problem because I chose it arbitrarily considering the shape of the final histogram.The bin of the two histograms that I compare is the same.I was wondering if the choice of a different bin for both histograms could affect the compatibility of the test.

Comment: Is the raw data not available?  I don't know what you mean by "compatibility of the test".  Do you mean the the *P*-value might be affected?

Comment: Yes I'm referring to the $P-value$.